# DotNetCore 3.1 global error handling, middle ware not getting called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to set up global exception handling code in .NetCore 3.1 webpai

My goal is to log unhandled exception before the app exits, using log4net.

I tried following several tutorials, one using a filter, and several using middelware and when I'm done and test it the middleware never gets called when I throw an exception thusly.

I have a filter already (which is commented out for testing the middle ware in case they were interacting) which does work, but can't use IOC to load an instanve of ILogger

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route( "/ThrowException" )]
        public JqGridReturnCV ThrowException()
        {
            log.LogTrace( "AdStudentController::ThrowException() - in" );

            throw new Exception( "This is a test Exception" );

            log.LogTrace( "AdStudentController::ThrowException() - out" );
        }
```

Here is my code for the middleware:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using log4net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using StudentPortal4Api.Dto;

namespace StudentPortal4Api.Utilities
{
    public class GlobalExceptionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        public readonly  ILogger         log;

        public GlobalExceptionMiddleware( RequestDelegate _next, ILogger _log )
        {
            next = _next;
            log = _log;
        }

        public async Task Invoke( HttpContext context )
        {
            try
            {
                await next( context );
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                var response = context.Response;
                response.ContentType = "application/json";

                switch ( ex )
                {
                    
                    default:
                        // unhandled error
                        log.Log( LogLevel.Error, " GlobalException:" + ex.ToString() ); 
                        break;
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    public class ErrorDetails
    {
        public int    StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string Message    { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject( this );
        }
    }

    public static class ExceptionMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureExceptionHandler( this IApplicationBuilder app, ILogger logger )
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler( appError =>
                                     {
                                         appError.Run( async context =>
                                                       {
                                                           context.Response.StatusCode  = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                                                           context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                                                           var contextFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                                                           if ( contextFeature != null )
                                                           {
                                                               logger.LogError( $"Something went wrong: {contextFeature.Error}" );
                                                               await context.Response.WriteAsync( new ErrorDetails()
                                                                                                      {
                                                                                                          StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode,
                                                                                                          Message    = "Internal Server Error."
                                                                                                      }.ToString() );
                                                           }
                                                       } );
                                     } );
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my configure method , where I suspect I'm doing something wrong in registering it

```
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ILogger log )
            {
                //code removed for clarity
    
    
                app.UseAuthorization();
    
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
    
                //Code removed for clarity
    
                // global error handler
                app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionMiddleware>();
                app.ConfigureExceptionHandler( log );
            }
        }
    }
```

anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please, try to reduce the codebase you are sharing to a [mcve]. Right now it has too much  unrelated code (specially the startup.cs).

Comment: Order matters. You can't just throw stuff in `Configure` willy-nilly. You are building a service pipeline in `Configure`. Try moving `app.UseExceptionHandler` above `app.UseEndpoints` line.

Comment: Removed more unneeded code.. though I had to have the answer to actually know for sure some of it wasn't needed, since it a OoOP bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a order issue [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#middleware-order)

change to:

```
 app.UseAuthorization();

 // global error handler
 app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionMiddleware>(); //custom Middleware Must be before endpoints and after auth. 

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

You will not need the  app.UseExceptionHandler.